# JSON data identical yet program fails?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, json, sbjson

I have an iOS app which gets some JSON from a server (in the form of NSData). I use the SBJson framework's parser to convert that to an NSDictionary object, like so:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *content = [parser objectWithData:data];
```

I then proceed to read objects from 'content' etc.

Now, this exact code has worked PERFECT using an old version of the SBJson framework. The program was fine. Then I implemented a new version of the SBJson framework and all of a sudden my program crashes when I try to do the same things with 'content' (To be more specific I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error).

My first thought was that the new SBJsonParser produced a slightly different file, and so I logged both the new and the old 'content' to text files and ran the 'diff' command on them from the command line. They are EXACTLY the same.

So, the ONLY change I made was to use the new SBJsonParser. What am I missing?

Comment: You may be over releasing an object that was once a leak, or possibly an API change or bug in the `SBJsonParser` version you are using if you have not changed your code since the upgrade. Either way [enable Zombies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) and track it down.

Comment: When I enable Zombies it doesn't crash, but when I disable them it crashes. And in the Zombie's profiler (Instruments) no zombies show up.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the SBJSON framework, you could try an alternative such as JSONKit or in > iOS 5 NSJSONSerialization class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change my code slightly:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *content = [[parser objectWithData:data] retain];
```